# ActiveMQ enqueued message java servicemix karaf command

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

i m working with **ActiveMQ ServiceMix** and i want to have enqueued message count / dequeued message count etc... in java. i want value like it is showed in ActiveMQ Console

```
Name    Number Of Pending Messages      Number Of Consumers     Messages Enqueued       Messages Dequeued       Views       Operations  
Consumer.ID-10-147-244-247-15461c6c293-38-0.Vir...  0   2   13  13  
Consumer.ID-10-147-244-247-15470570c61-108-0.Vi...  0   2   13  13
```

I want to get Messages Enqueued columns :)

My program start a session with consumer and listener's. All work fine.

But for monitoring I have wrote a *karaf command* that call my subscription object (subscription containt session/connection/queue etc...)

In my subscription i try this :

```
ActiveMQConnection activeMQConnection = ((ActiveMQConnection) connection);
ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue = getQueueConnection(queueName, activeMQConnection);

ActiveMQTopic a = AdvisorySupport.getConsumerAdvisoryTopic(activeMQQueue);
```

but next i don t know how to get `DestinationStatistics` to get all information about my queue/topic...

I try this too :

```
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(activeMQQueue);
```

but nothing interessting in browser.

if someone can help me to get my DestinationStatistics objetct ;)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i use QueueBrowser to know length of the queue, QueuBrowser just browse the queue without remove them so i can iterate and count number of message in any queue.